# Post Javascript variable to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I use Facebook JavaScript SDK.
I want to know how to post the Javascript variables to another page with GET or POST or any other way.
For example i have:

```
userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
```

How to post it to new page ?

```
location.href="http://www.walla.com/?info=" + info.id;
```

Not working

Comment: can you please show whole code ???

Answer (score 1):

Better use ajax for this ..

here is an example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type:'POST',  //POST or GET depending if you want to use _GET or _POST in php
       url:'your-page.php', //Effectively the form action, where it goes to.
       data:$('#txtName').val(),  //The data to send to the page (Also look up form serialise)
       success:function(e) {
            // On success this fill fire, depends on the return you will use in your page.
       }
     });
     return false;
   });
});
</script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Hope it works for u.

Answer (score 0):

That looks okay. You should be able to obtain info.id via `$_GET['info']` from PHP.

However, that's assuming `userInfo` is a simple string.

If it isn't, you may have to convert it to string first. One way to do that is through JSON as JSON is decodable at PHP's side using `json_decode()`.